# Округление float с точностью до 0.5

Tags: c#

Каким образом можно округлять значение float после точки к 5?

Пример:

```
value.23 = Целое значение не меняется, после точки 5.
value.85 = Целое увеличивается на 1, после точки 5,
```

Отрицательных значений не предусмотрено.

Comment: Расшифруйте пожалуйста свою запись в общепринятой математической нотации. В таком виде непонятны интервалы исходных значений и соответствующие им конечные значения. Отдельно стоит уточнить про отрицательные числа, т.к. они могут обрабатываться по-разному. если отрицательные значения не предполагается использовать - явно укажите это в вопросе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример из вопроса мною был умышленно проигнорирован т.к. имеет весьма странный вид:

```
value.85 = +value.5
```

непонятно что это означает.

---

Вот это решение должно сработать **(округляет всегда в большую сторону, в т.ч. минусовые числа. Как правильно обрабатывать минусовые числа в вопросе указано небыло)**:

```
Math.Ceiling(value / 0.5) * 0.5;
```

---

тестовый код:

```
var inputs = new[] { -1.4, -1.45, -1.4666666, -1.0, -1.6, 1.4, 1.45, 1.466666666, 1.0, 1.6 };

foreach (var value in inputs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", input, Math.Ceiling(value / 0.5) * 0.5);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

результат:

```
-1,4 => -1
-1,45 => -1
-1,4666666 => -1
-1 => -1
-1,6 => -1,5

1,4 => 1,5
1,45 => 1,5
1,466666666 => 1,5
1 => 1
1,6 => 2
```